# add a pop out dropdown list when choose a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I use Django 2.2.16 in windows 10.
In my frontend page, I have to achieve this function, after choosing a radio button, a dropdown list will pop out.
I have finished the radio button editing and know how to do dropdown list, but I do not know how I could achieve such kind of popout function after choosing the radio button.

HTML:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">    
              <form>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>&nbsp;Latest Available Semester
        </label>
 
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio">&nbsp;Specific Semester
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
```

PS: Pop out a widget in the page, that is, make a invisible widget visible, not pop up like alert in js.

Comment: To understand : Your popout function is a hidden visible feature ?

Comment: yep, make a invisible dropdown list pop out

Comment: I don't know if django can do this. But a js or jquery will works. Is it ok ? i can try to answer

Comment: ok, pls answer in js, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jquery answer. Let me know if you need additional comments.

```
<div class="row">
    <form>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="notspecific" checked>&nbsp;Latest Available Semester
        </label>

        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="specific">&nbsp;Specific Semester
        </label>
        <select id="dropdown" >
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="dog">Dog</option>
            <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    // hidden at init
    $('#dropdown').hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    // test the value of radio button to decide to show or hide the dropdown
        if ($(this).val() == 'specific') {
            $('#dropdown').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#dropdown').hide();
        };
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2 radio buttons and they are created using Django forms' RadioSelect widget? How can I add attributes to each of those radio buttons? Is there a way to do this? I hope you get this comment.